# Eigen3 stack or heap?

Tags: eigen, heap-memory, eigen3, stack-memory

If I write in a function the following local variable:

```
Eigen::VectorXd v = Eigen::Vector2d(1.0,2.0);
```

Is `v` allocated on the stack or on the heap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `v` itself is allocated on the stack and will contain one pointer and one Index variable. During the construction of `v` there will be additional 16 bytes allocated on the heap.

**Simplified**, something like this happens:

```
struct VectorXd {
    double* data;
    ptrdiff_t rows;
};


void foo(){
    VectorXd v;
    v.data = new double[2];  // actually uses an aligned malloc instead of new
    v.rows = 2;
    v.data[0] = 1.0; v.data[1] = 2.0;


    // At destruction:
    delete[] v.data;
}
```

To see what actually happens in your case, check out: https://godbolt.org/z/GYFmj0

For small objects you should almost always prefer to use fixed sized Vectors/Matrices, if you know the size at compile time.

Comment: Ok. I thought that I was allocating the data on the stack by using Vector2d, which is false apparently.

Comment: @MFnx `Vector2d` does allocate on the stack, and will in your case likely get optimized away entirely. But `VectorXd` will always allocate on the heap (as soon as it has `size>0`)

Comment: Is v going to be optizimed away? I understand that VectorXd(2) v; v<<1,2; is exactly the same?

Comment: No, `v` will allocate memory and deallocate it at destruction. `VectorXd(2)` and `Vector2d` is not the same.

Comment: Ok I understand the allocation/deallocation. But VectorXd v = Vector2d(1,2) and VectorXd v; v << 1,2; are equivalent, I understand. Correct?

Comment: The second case will fail, since `v` does never allocate memory. If, instead, you wrote `VectorXd v(2); v << 1,2;` it should be equivalent to the first (when compiled with sufficient optimization).